# Java JSch is throwing Auth Cancel Exception

Tags: java, putty, jsch

Simply trying to run the following Java code from Windows 10 to connect remote Linux server.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
```

But getting `Error: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel`

I can connect the same server from Putty though. In some other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901248/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-auth-cancel) it was suggested to use `setKnownHosts` method but not sure how to get that working.

**JSch LOG** (deleted few lines for security reasons):-

```
Connecting to xxx port xxx
Connection established
Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
...
...
aes256-ctr is not available.
aes192-ctr is not available.
aes256-cbc is not available.
aes192-cbc is not available.
CheckKexes: xxx
CheckSignatures: xxx
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
...
...
SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
Permanently added xxx (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Disconnecting from xxx port xxx
```

Comment: Stop guessing. Instead inspect a [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848) to identify the real root cause.

Comment: Thanks for that but did not help much. The log ends saying - `Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Disconnecting from <hostname> port <portno>`

Comment: That’s not true. Now you know that you really have a problem with authentication and not with host keys (known hosts). Add a complete log to your question.