# Connect to a linux system secured by RSA SecurID using ssh2 in Java

Tags: java, linux, ssh, sftp, securid

I want to create a connection from a Windows system to a Linux machine which uses RSA token Passcode for authentication and I want to run shell commands and get the output from the Java code. When logging into that Linux system using putty has the following steps:

1. Enter IP and port and connect
2. Enter username in the PuTTY terminal which asks "login as: "
3. Enter PASSCODE where we enter RSA SecurID

I have already tried connecting using `Jsch` package and it doesn't connect. I also tried a `jcabi-ssh` (http://ssh.jcabi.com/) which a wrapper for `Jsch`. None of them seem to work for me.

EDIT: I used the following code using the `Jsch` packages

```
        String host = "xxx";
        String user = "xxx";
        String password;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter rsa token: ");
        password = scanner.nextLine();

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 2222);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();
```

I get the following error after it:

`com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: myservername. RSA key fingerprint is ba:2b:70:2f:4f:fa:f6:20:31:56:e0:e8:8b:16:46:c9`

I found a solution by someone saying include this piece of code which sets StrictHostKeyChecking to "no":

```
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
```

Then my error changed to:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
```

Trying with that other `jcabi-ssh` implementation gives similar results.

Comment: "it doesn't connect" - i.e. step 1 is failing? So you're not getting as far as the RSA token?

Comment: Or is the TCP Or is the TCP connection made but then some negotiation failing? Do you get any error messages or exceptions?

Comment: @Rup check the edits

Comment: Thanks. [Auth cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901248/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-auth-cancel) sounds like it doesn't have an authentication method it can use. Maybe the RSA token value has a different code internally than password? I think your best bet would be to find the code in JSch that's generating the cancel and work out why, and if it's because it can't find a common authentication method then checking which values are known by both the client and the server.

Comment: I've had a quick look at the JSch code from SourceForge - annoyingly no source browser I can link to, but here's [an old snapshot on GitHub](https://github.com/is/jsch/) and the relevant bits haven't changed. It looks like this is triggered by JschAuthCancelException, so if you can get your debugger to break on that that would help you track down where this is coming from: it's triggered either by a public key that it can't decrypt, or password auth without a password, or if it's unable to show a password prompt (or if the user cancels an interactive password prompt).

Comment: You should try and find out which one of these you're hitting. If it's something unexpected then have a look at the loop where this is caught, as that's the loop over agreed authentication methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a dialog which will accept the passphrase at that point in time and establish connection. Here is what you need to integrate RSA SecureId - http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthPubKey.java.html

Comment: That example is obviously for private key authentication not SecureId, and he has the value he wants to use already - he doesn't need a dialog. Is there something else specific in that code he should be doing you're trying to highlight?

Comment: Obviously you will have to modify that code. Use com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthAgentException
com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSession
com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSessionFactory. You can google for examples which use RSA authagent.