# Maven install failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel

Tags: java, maven

I try to deploy to my work VDS.
I have bad error and don`t know how solve it.
I can't figure out what the problem is.
Through the terminal, the connection via the SSH protocol is stable

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.local.maven.plugins:dpkg-maven-plugin:1.13:install (install) on project service: Execution install of goal org.local.maven.plugins:dpkg-maven-plugin:1.13:install failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.local.maven.plugins:dpkg-maven-plugin:1.13:install (install) on project service: Execution install of goal org.local.maven.plugins:dpkg-maven-plugin:1.13:install failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: How is the connection via the SSH of the usual git terminal or client?

Comment: @WBLord Via git bash with password and private key

Comment: Do you have pass-phrase  and default name key?

Comment: @WBLord not default name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this error occurs due to a *passphrase* or a *non-default name* of the SSH key.
Try changing the private and public key to **id_rsa** and **id_rsa.pub**
To remove the passphrase, use `ssh-keygen -p`

Answer (score 0):

**Environment:**
Java.: 1.8.0_282
Maven: 3.8.6

**Plugin version:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Site configuration:**

```
<distributionManagement>
  <site>
    <id>server_to_deploy</id>
    <name>Project documentation</name>
    <url>scp://server_to_deploy/var/www/html/ref/${project.artifactId}</url>
  </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

**Credential configuration:**

```
<server>
  <id>server_to_deploy</id>
  <username>username</username>
  <privateKey>/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_deploy_server</privateKey>
  <configuration>
    <strictHostKeyChecking>no</strictHostKeyChecking>
    <preferredAuthentications>publicKey</preferredAuthentications>
    <interactive>false</interactive>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

**Key generation:**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_deploy_server
```

**Key implantation:**

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_deploy_server server_to_deploy
```

Note: on first run, password will be asked.

**Key test:**

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa server_to_deploy date
qui 02 mar 2023 11:24:10 -03
```

**Maven deploy:**

````
mvn site-deploy
server_to_deploymvn site:deploy -X
```[DEBUG] Deploying to 'scp://server_to_deploy/home/username/public_html/ref/test',
    Using credentials from server id 'server_to_deploy'
[DEBUG]  configureWagon 
[DEBUG] configureWagon server nexus
[DEBUG] configureWagon server nexus-snapshots
[DEBUG] configureWagon server nexus-releases
[DEBUG] repository protocol scp
[DEBUG] getProxy 'protocol': scp
[DEBUG] getProxy 'protocol': scp no ProxyInfo found
[DEBUG] Mapping url source calculation: 
[DEBUG] Mapped url: scp://server_to_deploy/home/username/public_html/ref/test to relative path: 
[DEBUG] authenticationInfo with id 'server_to_deploy': username
[DEBUG] connect with authenticationInfo and without proxyInfo
Using private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
scp://server_to_deploy/home/username/public_html/ref/test - Session: Connection refused
scp://server_to_deploy/home/username/public_html/ref/test - Session: Disconnecting  
scp://server_to_deploy/home/username/public_html/ref/test - Session: Disconnected
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.747 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-02T11:59:45-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.9.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Error uploading site: Cannot connect. Reason: invalid privatekey: [B@a6dffdb -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.9.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Error uploading site
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error uploading site
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.push (AbstractDeployMojo.java:454)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deployTo (AbstractDeployMojo.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.execute (AbstractDeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot connect. Reason: invalid privatekey: [B@a6dffdb
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.AbstractJschWagon.openConnectionInternal (AbstractJschWagon.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection (AbstractWagon.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect (AbstractWagon.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect (AbstractWagon.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.push (AbstractDeployMojo.java:418)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deployTo (AbstractDeployMojo.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.execute (AbstractDeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@a6dffdb
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load (KeyPair.java:664)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load (KeyPair.java:561)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance (IdentityFile.java:40)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity (JSch.java:407)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity (JSch.java:388)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.AbstractJschWagon.openConnectionInternal (AbstractJschWagon.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.openConnection (AbstractWagon.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect (AbstractWagon.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.connect (AbstractWagon.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.push (AbstractDeployMojo.java:418)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:311)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deployTo (AbstractDeployMojo.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.execute (AbstractDeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
````

Comment: For some reason, jsch use a quite different authentication method.

TLDL;
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901248/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-auth-cancel/75619432#75619432]Create a rsa-sha2-512 key (using a PEM format))

[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721606/ssh-server-gives-userauth-pubkey-key-type-ssh-rsa-not-in-pubkeyacceptedalgorit](Original solution)